# Problems with OR operator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am using a foreach loop which repeats itself based on the amount of items in a list. Each time it repeats, it checks if two textboxes have a value of "0". If they (or one of them) does, then I check if the summary value of the hour it is iterating on is (or is not. in the case of the part after the "end" comment) a certain value. If it isn't, then I used an OR operator (||) to do the same thing to the next one. However, this is not working.

I am using debug.writeline to see where the loop finds a match. It is, for whatever reason, always at 0 - even if the value of hour.summary for iteration 0 is "Rain", something which should make the if not be able to find a match and instead fire the else.

```
foreach (var hour in result.Hourly.Hours)
{
    //Start
    if (starttemp.Text == "0")
    {
        if ((hour.Summary == "Rain") || (hour.Summary == "Snow") || (hour.Summary == "Drizzle") || (hour.Summary == "Light Rain") || (hour.Summary == "Light Snow") || (hour.Summary == "Heavy Rain") || (hour.Summary == "Heavy Snow"))
        { starttemp.Text = hour.Temperature.ToString(); Debug.WriteLine("SET START WITH " + hour.Summary + " AT HOUR " + increment); }
        else
        { }
    }
    //End
    if (endtemp.Text == "0")
    {
        if ((hour.Summary != "Rain") || (hour.Summary != "Snow") || (hour.Summary != "Drizzle") || (hour.Summary != "Light Rain") || (hour.Summary != "Light Snow") || (hour.Summary != "Heavy Rain") || (hour.Summary != "Heavy Snow"))
        { endtemp.Text = hour.Temperature.ToString(); Debug.WriteLine("SET END WITH " + hour.Summary + " AT HOUR " + increment); }
        else
        { }
    }
    increment = increment + 1;
}
```

Comment: What is the "Hour" object ? Are you sure about your second IF with the the OR and the "!=" ? Because it seems to me that as long as hour.Summary is not "Rain", that statement is not gonna fire; maybe " | " instead of " || " ?

Comment: Hour is an "HourDataPoint" object, included in the forecast.io PCL. Tried replacing || with | and it still outputted this, which isn't what i want: SET START WITH Light Rain AT HOUR 0 (newline)
SET END WITH Light Rain AT HOUR 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
if ((hour.Summary != "Rain") || (hour.Summary != "Snow") || (hour.Summary != "Drizzle") || (hour.Summary != "Light Rain") || (hour.Summary != "Light Snow") || (hour.Summary != "Heavy Rain") || (hour.Summary != "Heavy Snow"))
```

Will always be true...

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but i think you should replace the || with &&

Comment: I always thought of OR like this: if i have a cat OR a dog then..., but that really doesn't seem to be what it does. AND works.

Comment: You understand OR correctly, but you are asking if something is _different_ from a OR _different_ from b...

    Any string that you input will always either be different from "Rain" or different from "Snow"